# double match a data.frame

Tags: r

I'd like to do a double match on a data.frame to extract row indices.  For example, in the following data.frame, I want to match first on match1, and within each element of match1, I want to match by match2.  Think of this as a double-sort (first by name, then by date) except that I'm not sorting, I'm matching

```
test = data.frame( name = c( "bob" , "jane","adam","jane" ,"bob" , "adam" ) , date = as.Date(c(1,2,2,1,2,1)))
match1 = c( "jane" , "adam", "bob")
match2 = c( as.Date(c(2,1)))
result = c( 2,4,3,6,5,1 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for your code to work as written, you need the `zoo` library loaded (it masks `as.Date`)

```
library("zoo")
```

It seem what you want it the indicies of the data.frame that correspond to the data.frame sorted by `name` according to `match1` and then by `date` according to `match2`.  You can use factors to create this ordering, and then `order` to get the indicies.

```
order(factor(test$name, match1), factor(as.character(test$date), as.character(match2)))
```

The `as.character` is needed to coerce the dates to characters so that they can be turned into factors with the right ordering.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check for a double-match is to do a double-sort on "test" (call this test2) and test for the equality of "test" and "test2"

Comment: huh?  I'm not trying to double-sort, I'm trying to double-match.  And i'm trying to extract indices, not test for equality.